# SQL cast() INT to CHAR not working in UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to retroactively add sequencing information to my SQL database by setting the default order equal to the `ID` which is currently present. The `ID` column is an `INT` and the `sequence` column is `TEXT`.

I want the `sequence` column to be in the following format: `["1", "1", "1"]`

The following works:

```
UPDATE products p
SET  p.sequence =  p.id
```

For some reason, whenever I get a query to work (even with `cast()`), it adds the values instead of concatenating them...

For instance, I have tried:

```
UPDATE products p 
SET p.sequence = cast(p.id as char(10))+cast(p.id as char(10))
```

And the `sequence` columns all change to the value of `id`+`id`, e.g. ID = 1, sequence = 2...

Then if I try:

```
UPDATE products p
SET  p.sequence =  '["'+p.id+'", "'+p.id+'", "'+p.id+'"]'
```

Result: The values of `sequence` are now three times the value of `ID`, i.e. ID = 2, sequence = 6. It is adding the IDs instead of concatenating them.

And if I `cast()` the same query, it says "0 Rows affected":

```
UPDATE products p
SET  p.sequence =  '["'+cast(p.id as char(10))+'", "'+cast(p.id as char(10))+'", "'+cast(p.id as char(10))+'"]'
```

Comment: sql server or mysql?

Comment: MySQL (w/ PHPMyAdmin interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty easy way to do what you want is to use `concat()` and `concat_ws()`:

```
update products p
    set p.sequence = concat('["',
                            concat_ws('","', p.id, p.id, p.id,
                            '"]');
```

The problem with your query is that `+` means addition in MySQL, not string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I thought I read + was concatenation but I guess not. You may want to update your answer for future reference, there is a small syntax error, this is correct: `update products p
    set p.sequence = concat('["',
                            concat_ws('","', p.id, p.id, p.id),
                            '"]')`